# Why USB sticks automatically mounted only under root?

Tags: usb, sudo

I've just installed Ubuntu 12.04 and updated all the packages. If I connect a USB stick to the PC it is not mounted automatically, if I run, say, `mount -t vfat /dev/sdc1 /media/usb_stick` I get `Permission denied` result. So the command returns a successful result only under `sudo`. I'm the only user of the PC. What's is wrong? With former versions of Ubuntu it was fine.

Answer (score 0):

What are the permissions on the mount point? If you run `ls -l /media` What permissions do you see on the directory?

Comment: `vkirsan@sea:0:~> ls -l /media`

`total 12`

`drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul 17 18:13 ash/`

`drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul 27 19:25 clay/`

`drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul 14 01:29 glint/`

`vkirsan@sea:0:~>`

Comment: I have deleted those subfolders, hoping that they will be automatically created when I insert a stick (as on other machine with no such a problem). But still result is the same. Could it be that I have such a restriction due to the domain policy? I'm using LikeWise Open to be in an AD domain.

Answer (score 0):

If your USB stick is formatted ntfs make sure you have the NTFS Fuse programs installed.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g ntfsprogs;
```

ntfs support seems to have been removed since 12.04LTS

Comment: Thank you. I tried USB sticks only of FAT and ext4 file systems.